# Como puedo usar la función require() en el lado del cliente?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber si hay una buena biblioteca javascript para manejar módulos, estilo node.js, pero del lado del cliente. Con las siguientes características:

- No es necesario poder reutilizar los módulos ya existentes de node.js (Server side).
- Permita una carga modular de la aplicación web(que no sea necesario cargar todos los scripts al inicio).
- Sintaxis similar a módulos de node.js al definir los exports en los módulos.
- Cargar módulos mediante ajax de manera asíncrona.
- Que sea capaz de resolver dependencias de los módulos. Por ejemplo si hago `require(view)` el modulo view pueda depender del módulo model.

Comment: Si se parece un poco, pero ninguna respuesta me parece suficientemente concluyente. Y por cierto en realidad es un aporte me estoy autorrespondiendo.

Comment: ClientModulesJS necesita que se reprogramen los módulos. O sea no es el mismo require. Una posibilidad es usar `require-bro`. npmjs.com/package/require-bro tiene la ventaja de que no se necesita reprogramar los módulos. Lo que ande en el servidor anda en el cliente (con limitaciones, algunas obvias, no se puede usar fs, y otras no tanto, el módulo tiene que crearse en modo compatible).

Comment: ClientModulesJS no propone que uses los módulos que ya hiciste de node.js, ofrece una manera de hacer modulos PARA el cliente al "estilo" de node.js, una diferencia importante con require-bro es: _"The required module must be included in previous <scripts> and must have define a global variable with the same name."_ ClientModulesJS no requiere eso, puedes hacer aplicaciones muy complejas y ClientModulesJS se encargará de traer los módulos del servidor cuando se le requiera. la idea es tener una carga de módulos similar a node.js pero de manera asíncrona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [ClientModulesJS](https://github.com/capipo/ClientModulesJS), la principal diferencia con los módulos de node.js es que ClientModulesJS importa los modulos de manera asíncrona, una vez que lo integres a tu proyecto podrás hacer algo como estó:

```
require('modules/users')
  .then(function(imports) {
    // imports es el objeto exports del modulo users
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error!!!', error);
  });
```

Aquí hay mas información [README (español)](https://github.com/capipo/ClientModulesJS/blob/master/README.es.md)